# Will the use of event handler written in super component controller be deprecated?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Lightning developer guide says that events can be inherited.

> A sub component that extends a super component can handle events fired
>   by the super component. The sub component automatically inherits the
>   event handlers from the super component.
>
> The super and sub component can handle the same event in different
>   ways by adding an  tag to the sub component. The
>   framework doesn't guarantee the order of event handling.

But it also says that

> We don't recommend using inheritance of client-side controllers as
>   this feature may be deprecated in the future to preserve better
>   component encapsulation. We recommend that you put common code in a
>   helper instead.

Comment: No one knows for sure but you better code like it will be or have trouble later. Consider yourself warned so to speak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research following are my observations -

- The event registered using

  ```
    <aura:registerEvent name="sampleComponentEvent" type="c:compEvent"/>
  ```

  will be inherited and recommended.
- Each sub component should declare its own handler.
- Any abstract component ideally should not have any controller.